# AWS Lambda : Unable to import module 'mail': No module named mail

Tags: javascript, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm following this little tutorial for sending an email when an object is uploaded in a S3 bucket. To use it with Lambda I created a .zip file with following structure:

mail.js
/node_modules

The mail.js has following code:

```
var MailComposer = require('mailcomposer').MailComposer,
    mailcomposer = new MailComposer();
var ses =
    new aws.SES({
        accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'});

s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    //error handling
  } else {
    mailcomposer.setMessageOption({
      from: 'chirer@gmail.com’,
      to: 'sjuif@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Test’,
      body: 's3://' + bucket + '/' + key,
      html: 's3://' + bucket + '/' + key +
            '&lt;br/&gt;&lt;img src="cid:' + key + '" /&gt;'
    });
    var attachment = {
      contents: data.Body,
      contentType: 'image/png',
      cid: key
    };
    mailcomposer.addAttachment(attachment);
    mailcomposer.buildMessage(function(err, messageSource) {
      if (err) {
        // error handling
      } else {
        ses.sendRawEmail({RawMessage: {Data: messageSource}}, function(err, data) {
          if(err) {
            // error handling
          } else {
              context.done(null, data);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

When I create a lambda function I do the following :

1. In the select blueprint menu I select "s3-get-object-python"
2. I choose my bucket
3. As event I choose "Put"
4. I click "next"
5. I give a name to the lambda function and choose "upload a .zip file"
6. I upload the zip file with mail.js and the node_modules directory
7. As handler I fill in "mail.handler"
8. As role I choose "S3 execution role". The wizard gives now a new screen where I click "view policy document". I edit the document, the document is now like:

   ```
   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
           "logs:CreateLogGroup",
           "logs:CreateLogStream",
           "logs:PutLogEvents"
         ],
         "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
       },
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
           "s3:GetObject",
           "s3:PutObject",
           "ses:SendEmail",
           "ses:SendRawEmail"
         ],
         "Resource": [
           "*"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
9. I click 'Allow' and go back to the previous screen
10. Then I choose next en enables the lambda function

When I now upload a png file I get the following error in my log.

```
START RequestId: a4401d96-c0ef-11e5-9ae4-8f38a4f750b6 Version: $LATEST
**Unable to import module 'mail': No module named mail**

END RequestId: a4401d96-c0ef-11e5-9ae4-8f38a4f750b6
REPORT RequestId: a4401d96-c0ef-11e5-9ae4-8f38a4f750b6  Duration: 0.35 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 9 MB
```

I don't know why because i'm sure the mail.js is in the root of my .Zip file

Comment: I'd say it looks like you are confusing Python and Javascript here a bit - both in your tag and in your description you mention Python but the code you reference is Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that Lambda can't find the lib.  It can't be in proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages or proj/lib64/python2.7/site-packages

It MUST BE inside proj/ itself.  I ran into the same problem with MySQL-python and wrote a howto:

http://www.iheavy.com/2016/02/14/getting-errors-building-amazon-lambda-python-functions-help-howto/

HTH
-Sean

Comment: well... have u had it inside the main folder and had the handler and filename configured correctly and still gotten the same error.?..cause i have and its blowin my mind